# 'npm run build' often freezes my entire server

Tags: reactjs

Perhaps 75-80% of the time, I can run `git pull` on my EC2 Linux server, then `npm run build` to create a production-ready build of my React app. On occasion, however, after running `npm run build`, the whole server freezes and I have to force restart several times just to get it up and running again.

It seems to be entirely random. It seems awfully bizarre some JavaScript compilation (I guess?) process can knock over an entire server, but it happens frequently enough that it's obviously not caused by anything else.

Is this something anyone's encountered?

Comment: Can you share the `build` script with us?

Comment: The build process can take a lot of memory, what instance of EC2 are you using? Try to increase the ram on your server

Comment: I had this issue once in a project before switching to Webpack (from Browserify). The build process had many in-house scripts that were moving folders and files around and could cause an infinite loop of the (sub)process. It was also seemingly random, but it never caused any kind of crash, we just had to kill the process and start over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build process in resource consuming, and this is exepected. This is why in my deploy pipelines often I launch the build locally before deploy (it takes about 6 minutes on some apps, depending on complexity and webpack configuration), or I setup another server that is only used for build process.

Comment: Or, just add a swap partition to the AWS instance that probably doesn't have one ;)

Comment: You can build from localhost then use `rsync` to copy the sourcecode:
For example sync from current directory to the app folder in the remote server with IP 112.78.3.103:

`rsync -avzP root@112.78.3.104:/app ./`

Answer (score 2):

I realise I'm late to the party, but I've just solved this problem by adding a swap partition to my Debian 11 AWS instance (I followed DigitalOcean's instructions for adding swap: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-debian-11)

Answer (score 0):

All this depends on the configuration of your server instance. Actually build process take a lot of processor power and memory ,so the server might reach out of memory while building.

You can consider upgrading your server Or one temporary solution for it can be that you can build the react app on your local machine and simply serve that build folder through the server.

Comment: No need to upgrade - just add a swap partition